# Prove $\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2 (\sin(x))^{2/3}} < \infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I seek to prove convergence of the following integral
$$\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2 (\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{3}}}$$

My attempted solution is as follows.

I use the identity
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^{2x-1} (u) \cos^{2y - 1}(u) du = \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x + y)}$$

Choose $x = \frac{1}{6}$ and $y = \frac{1}{2}$.

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{\pi}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x^2 (\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{3}}} & \stackrel{?}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n \pi}^{(n + 1) \pi} \frac{dx}{x^2(\sin(x))^{\frac{2}{3}}} \\
& \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^2 \pi^2} \frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)} \\
& = \frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)} \frac{2}{\pi^2} \frac{\pi^2}{6} \\
& = \frac{1}{3} \frac{\Gamma\left(-\frac{2}{3}\right) \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{1}{6}\right)} < \infty \\
\end{align}
$$

**Question:** I know that special care must be given to justifying the interchange of an infinite sum and an integral. Is my first equality my first equality (marked by the ?) correct? If so, I would be very appreciative to see other peoples alternative methods of solving this problem.

Comment: Is the power of $\sin x$ $2/3$ or $3/2$? What happens when $\sin x\leq 0$?

Comment: Assuming it is $|\sin(x)|^{2/3}$, one way to go is to use Holder's inequality. You can't do it globally but you can do it on, say, a period of $|\sin(x)|$ and check whether the bound you get is summable.

Comment: Sorry, $\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: But $\sin x$ has infinitely many zeros in $[\pi,\infty)$ so that the integral does not exist?  Even if it had just finitely many zeros the integral would not exist, except you start using principal values at the singularities.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts They are each integrable singularities, like $|x|^{-2/3}$ at 0. (Assuming you sort out the branch cut issue that Gary pointed out.)

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts I numerically evaluated the integral and saw that it roughly converges to about 3 or 4. (If I remember correctly.) I believe the phenomena we observe is akin to Torricelli's trumpet, wherein the area covered by the function is finite although it has infinite "surface area" or in this case length. At least, those are my two sense.

Comment: Also, having gone through and actually done it, general Holder turns out to be overkill, you can just use $x^{-2} \leq ((2n-1)\pi)^{-2} \leq n^{-2},n=1,2,\dots$ and sum. Nothing fancy required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have some consistent way to define $\sin(x)^{-2/3}$ on all of $[\pi,\infty)$ other than the singularities. It doesn't really matter what that is, as long as it has absolute value $|\sin(x)|^{-2/3}$.

With that in mind, you have

$$\int_\pi^\infty x^{-2} |\sin(x)|^{-2/3} dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((2n-1)\pi)^{-2} \int_{(2n-1)\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi} |\sin(x)|^{-2/3} dx \leq C \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-2}<\infty.$$

Comment: How would one justify $\displaystyle \int_\pi^\infty x^{-2} |\sin(x)|^{-2/3} dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty ((2n-1)\pi)^{-2} \int_{(2n-1)\pi}^{(2n+1)\pi} |\sin(x)|^{-2/3} dx$? Would it be as simple as evaluating partial sums from the integral, or would one have to demonstrate that everything converges uniformly. Given that the intent of the problem is to prove convergence, I feared that exchanging a sum with the integral would be circular logic if it required uniform convergence. Can we justify this exchange without uniform convergence, or would such a consideration not even apply in this case.

Comment: @Talmsmen There's no difficulty doing the exchange in this setting because you have positive functions, so you can invoke the monotone convergence theorem (at least in the Lebesgue theory). Besides that all I am doing is dividing up the domain of integration into the intervals $[(2n-1)\pi,(2n+1)\pi]$ and then giving a pointwise estimate of the integrand on each of those intervals.

Comment: Thank you! One final question, if the series generated by partitioning the integral was only conditionally convergent, would the Riemann Rearrangement Theorem invalidate all attempts to change the order of summation? Although my analysis course covered proofs of these ideas, I do not feel that I have had ample time to develop an intuition for their applications.

Comment: @Talmsmen Then it would depend on whether you demand absolute convergence of the integral itself or not. If you do (as in the Lebesgue theory) then the integral would just not exist. If you don't (as in the improper Riemann setting) then there wouldn't be a problem.